# Got error after upgrade spring-web version

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I got error after upgrade the spring-web version to after 6.0.0, previous is 5.3.20

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
```

```
Cannot access 'status': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'ResponseStatusException'

is ResponseStatusException -> {
                    serverWebExchange.response.statusCode = throwable.status
         }
```

Comment: Don't. You shoud be upgrading **all** your spring dependencies and not just 1, all the versions of the `org.springframework` dependencies have to match else you might (and will) run into weird issues (like this one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring 5.3.x `ResponseStatusException` used to have `getStatus()` available directly as you can see in the java doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/

In version 6.0.x it was changed and `ResponseStatusException` extends from `ErrorResponseException` which does not have the `getStatus()` method directly available.

Instead, you need to call `responseStatusException.getBody().getStatus()` in order to access the status correctly. Check the java doc for details https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/ErrorResponseException.html

From your question it is not clear if you access status directly in your code or if this code is part of some library. If it is part of the library, then you would need to upgrade the version of the library to the one compatible with spring 6.